# R Code Option Pricing: cycle for optimisation

Tags: r, optimization, tree

I’m trying to generate a tree that illustrate the evolution of an underlying following the geometric Brownian motion. the biggest problem is the matrix that evolve at each node 3^n therefore already in n=4 I have 27 cycle for: How can I optimise the code and be able to increase the number of node to for example 20.(therefore the matrix will have 3^20 rows).
I want to keep that kind of structure for my tree, and not the common with up/down/same.
here is the code:

```
sigma=0.15  # questo l'ho scelto io 
hist_sigma<-sd(AAPL$AAPL.Close)
S<-matrix(0,nrow = 27,ncol = 4)
S0=S[1,1]<-last(AAPL$AAPL.Close)
T=90/360
set.seed(22)
Z<-matrix(data = 0,nrow = 27, ncol = 3)
for (i in 1:27) {
  Z[i,]<-rnorm(3,mean = 0,sd=1)
  
}



for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 2:2) {
    S[i,j]<-S[1,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
  }
}

 for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 3:3) {
    S[i,j]<-S[1,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
 }

for (i in 4:6) {
  for (j in 3:3) {
    S[i,j]<-S[2,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 7:9) {
  for (j in 3:3) {
    S[i,j]<-S[3,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[1,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}
for (i in 4:6) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[2,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 7:9) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[3,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}
for (i in 10:12) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[4,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}
for (i in 13:15) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[5,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 16:18) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[6,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}
for (i in 19:21) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[7,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 22:24) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[8,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}

for (i in 25:27) {
  for (j in 4:4) {
    S[i,j]<-S[9,j-1]*(exp((r-1/2*sigma^2)*(120/360) + sigma*(sqrt((120/360))*Z[i,j-1])))
    
  }
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to worry about efficiency.

```
 S<-matrix(0,nrow=3^20,ncol=4)
```

will give you the following error message:

```
Error in matrix(0, nrow = 3^20, ncol = 4) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(0, nrow = 3^20, ncol = 4) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Comment: yeah is more about a problem of capacity, but I wanted find a function that describe this cycles for in order to save time in computing hundred of them